# how to convert UTC to India local time using golang

Tags: datetime, go, time

Mentioning the code below

```
 loc, _ := time.LoadLocation("Asia/Kolkata")
        now := time.Now().In(loc)
        fmt.Println("Location : ", loc, " Time : ", now)
        visit.Time = now
```

getting UTC time but i need to get IST in my datastore

Comment: HINT: https://golang.org/pkg/time/#FixedZone

Comment: It works on the Go Playground, and gives time in IST: [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/sd62GE8tU63). Most likely your `LoadLocation()` fails, do check the returned error! And why is this tagged with [tag:google-cloud-datastore]?

Comment: You're not showing the output of your print statement. Anyone trying will see `..... IST`. The value of `visit.Time` will just be a timestamp (timezones are just for displaying), if you want that to be displayed in `IST`, you'll need to specify the timezone at printing time.

Comment: @Marc Location : Asia/Kolkata Time : 2009-11-11 04:30:00 +0530 IST
but getting UCT time only

Comment: Then what is the problem? This is working exactly as expected. But to repeat: `time.Time` doesn't care about the timezone, timezones are for display only.

Comment: @ Marc But it is not Current time of IST 

i need this for at what time the record created exactly

Comment: `time.Now` is the current time on that machine as a number of seconds since Jan 1st 0001 at 00:00 UTC. It does not matter where you are, as long as your clock is correct, `time.Now` will say the same thing. Once again: timezones are used for display purposes only, they do not change the value of `time.Time`. Depending on how you insert it into your datastore, you may need to specify the timezone, but you're not showing that code or saying which datastore.

Comment: Or are you talking about the output on the playground? That's not going to be the actual time as the playground fakes a lot of system utilities. See [this blog post](https://blog.golang.org/playground) for details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/), this is working as expected.

> [About the Playground](https://play.golang.org/)
>
> The Go Playground is a web service that runs on golang.org's servers.
>   The service receives a Go program, compiles, links, and runs the
>   program inside a sandbox, then returns the output.
>
> There are limitations to the programs that can be run in the
>   playground:
>
> In the playground the time begins at 2009-11-10 23:00:00 UTC
>   (determining the significance of this date is an exercise for the
>   reader). This makes it easier to cache programs by giving them
>   deterministic output.
>
> The article "[Inside the Go Playground](https://blog.golang.org/playground)" describes how the playground is
>   implemented.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    loc, _ := time.LoadLocation("Asia/Kolkata")
    now := time.Now().In(loc)
    fmt.Println("Location : ", loc, " Time : ", now)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/l8t3BnQATg7

Output:

```
Location :  Asia/Kolkata  Time :  2009-11-11 04:30:00 +0530 IST
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct argument for IST is "Asia/Calcutta" not "Asia/Kolkata". Here is the complete list https://golang.org/src/time/zoneinfo_abbrs_windows.go

Comment: Asia/Kolkata works

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the issue is that the datastore converts all times to UTC.
In my case i was using firestore to store timestamps and when parsing the documents to my struct the mapping converted timestamps to utc.